# Java integration with Docu Sign

Tags: java, spring-boot, docusignapi

I am trying to integrate docusign with java application.

I am following Github example which is working.
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client

Here I am just changing Integrator key,clientId and private key but is not working.
https://github.com/docusign/docusign-java-client/blob/master/src/test/java/SdkUnitTests.java

Here I have attached how I am copying key and id etc...
https://gitlab.com/sanju24689/docusign

Here I have also attached my code also.

It's giving me error like

> "com.docusign.esign.client.ApiException: Error while requesting an
>   access token: POST https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token returned
>   a response status of 400 Bad Request"

See the stack trace [image]

Comment: "It is not working" doesn't describe the problem exactly. What is not working? Do you get any error messages?

Comment: @JensV please check I have updated

Comment: And the stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Have you done explicit User Consent of the UserId - ef27e777-c6fc-4385-91ce-63dafab5385b as explained in Step 1 in [JWT Doc](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/guides/authentication/oauth2-jsonwebtoken)

Answer (score 0):

Please try starting with the Java webapp that is ready to go--it is a complete project.

See [eg-03-java-auth-code-grant](https://github.com/docusign/eg-03-java-auth-code-grant)

Comment: Thanks, for your quick response,I don't want to explicitly sign user my scenario is like from the frontend when use click on sign button on that basis from the backend(Java/Spring) one email will be sent to signer.

Comment: I am sorry, I don't understand your comment. Please open a new question about what you want to do.